# check what is the first word in a string

Tags: string, actionscript-3, cpu-word

Is it possible, in AS3 code, to check what is the first word in a string a do something if it's a particular word ?

Exemple :

```
var str:String = mySharedObject.data.theDate;  //monday 21 january 2015

if (first word of str is "monday" or "apple"){
Do that
}else{
Do that instead
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you can :

- 1) Find index of the first space and store it.
- 2) Extract a substring starting at 0 to index found above (and store it if you want).
- 3) Compare substring with condition and continue.

So your code can be like this for example :

```
var str:String = 'hello world, world hello';
var i:int = str.indexOf(' ');   
var first_word:String = str.substr(0, i);

if(first_word == 'hello' || first_word == 'world')
{
    // ...
} 
else 
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1, because `String.indexOf() + String.substr()` is faster than `String.split()`. I also added an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can using the the [String.Split](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split()) function to break a string into an Array of Strings:

```
    var str:String = "monday 21 january 2015" ; // mySharedObject.data.theDate;

    // Split the string into an array of 'words' using RegEx
    var wordArray:Array = str.split(/\W+/g);

    //if (first word of str is "monday" or "apple"){
    if (wordArray[0] == "monday" || wordArray[0] == "apple") {
        trace("do that");
    } else {
        trace("do that instead")
    }
```